# Output a paragraph with line breaks in Django inside a list item

Tags: python, html, django

I have a bulletin board on a Django website. A single bulletin body is defined as `bulletin_body = models.TextField('Body', max_length=5000)` in class `Bulletin` inside `models.py`.

When a bulletin body is placed in a template as a separate paragraph, it displays all the line breaks that the body contains as expected. That is, `<h2>{{bulletin.bulletin_body|linebreaksbr}}</h2>` works fine.

But when a bulletin body is a list element, (e.g. in a page that contains bulletin feed) no line breaks are displayed. Example:

```
<ul>
    {% for bulletin in latest_bulletin_list %}
        <li>{{bulletin.bulletin_body|linebreaksbr}}</li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

I've only found answers suggesting to check if the model is `TextField` and to use `linebreaks` or `linebreaksbr` tag. I follow both advice and still can't display line breaks.

**Edit:**

Here are all tags around the list item:

```
<body>
    <div class="main_container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="column right">
                <div class="bulletin_wrapper">
                    {% if latest_bulletin_list %}
                        <ul>
                            {% for bulletin in latest_bulletin_list %}
                                        <li><h2>{{bulletin.bulletin_body|linebreaksbr}}</h2></li>
                            {% endfor %}
                        </ul>
                    {% else %}
                        <p>No bulletins are available.</p>
                    {% endif %}
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

CSS definitions for classes:

`main_container` and `body` don't have any definition as of now.

```
.row {
    margin:auto;
}

/* Clear floats after the columns */
.row:after {
    content: "";
    display: table;
    clear: both;
}

.column {
    float: left;
    padding: 10px;
}

.right {
    width: 40%;
 }

.bulletin_wrapper {
    text-align: left;
    margin-top: 10px;
    width: 95%;
}


ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-size: 12px;
}

ul a {
    color: #00e040;
    font-weight: 600;
}

ul a:hover {
    color:#00e040;
}
```

Comment: @PRMoureu Please see my edit.

Comment: i cannot reproduce this issue, even by adding the css styles  (with django version 11), did you try different browser ?

Comment: @PRMoureu I wasn't restarting the server after making changes to templates... Just started using Django recently, after using Meteor for a while where dev server restarts automatically on file change. `linebreaksbr` tag works everywhere now.

Comment: indeed..changes in the templates are not detected, but they do in views, models... but you don't need to restart the server to get the new version of templates